# Fourier transform of a piecewise linear which does not vanish at infinity

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Good evening everyone.

I wish to take the Fourier transform of the following piecewise function:

$$ f(x) =  \begin{cases}
\beta & \text{if } x < -\alpha \\
\frac{-\beta}{2\alpha} (x - \alpha) & \text{if } -\alpha < x < \alpha \\
0 & \text{if } x > \alpha \end{cases}
\quad (\alpha,\,\beta> 0) $$

I tried applying the definition:

$$ \begin{split}
\hat{f}(\omega) & = \int_{\Bbb R} f(x) e^{-i\omega x}\,dx \\
& = \beta \int_{-\infty}^{-\alpha}e^{-i\omega x} \, dx + \frac{-\beta}{2\alpha} \int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha} (x - \alpha) e^{-i\omega x} \, dx \\
\end{split} \tag{1} $$

But clearly, this integral does not converge. On the other hand, I read that

$$ \hat{u}(\omega) = \frac{1}{i\omega} + \pi\delta(\omega) \tag{2}$$

where $u$ is the unit step function

$$ u(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } x < 0 \\
1 & \text{if } x > 0 \end{cases} $$

and $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function. I don't completely understand $(2)$ but I take it for granted.

Then, I wrote $f$ as a sum of unit step functions as follows:

$$ f(x) = \beta u(-x-\alpha) + \frac{-\beta}{2\alpha} (x - \alpha)(u(x+\alpha) - u(x-\alpha)) \tag{3}$$

I think I can use $(2)$ and the linearity of the Fourier transform and complete the calculation.

Is this a valid approach? Any references would be appreciated, thank you.

---

**Edit:** I have continued my calculation based on Jean Marie's answer (and dropped the $\beta$ term):

$$ \hat{f}(k)/\beta = \delta(k) + \frac{1}{2\alpha} \hat{r}(k) (-2i) \sin(2\pi\alpha k) $$

$$ = \delta(k) + \frac{1}{2\alpha} \left( \frac{i}{4\pi}\delta'(k)-\frac{1}{4\pi^2 k^2} \right) (-2i) \sin(2\pi\alpha k) $$

$$ = \delta(k) + \frac{1 - i\pi k^2\delta'(k)}{4\alpha\pi^2 k^2} \, i \sin(2\pi\alpha k) $$

Apply the identity $k^2\delta'(k)=0$

$$ = \delta(k) + \frac{1}{4\alpha\pi^2 k^2} \, i \sin(2\pi\alpha k) $$

Then use $\text{sinc}(x) = \sin(\pi x)/\pi x$

$$  = \delta(k) + \frac{1}{2\pi k} i \, \text{sinc}(2\alpha k) $$

Comment: It has to be considered in the distributional sense. Your function (that should be shifted by $\beta/2$ in order for it to become an odd function, easier to manage) has a derivative which is a rectangular function ; its FT is a cardinal sine ; then use formula relating the FT of a derivative of $f$ and the FT of $f$, taking into account values at infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler approach than the one I had proposed in my comment.

I have taken the "other" definition of Fourier Transform (I am used to it in the framework of Signal Processing) :

$$\hat{f}(k) := \int_{\Bbb R} f(x) e^{-2 i \pi k x}\,dx.$$

Let us consider the "ramp function" : $r(x)=\max(x,0)$ whose Fourier Transform is known to be :

$$\hat{r}(k)=\dfrac{i}{4 \pi}\delta'(k)-\dfrac{1}{4 \pi^2 k^2}\tag{1}$$

(see ([How does one derive the Fourier transform of the Ramp function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1920602))).

As your function can be written

$$f(x)=\beta+\dfrac{\beta}{2\alpha}(r(x-\alpha)-r(x+\alpha)), \tag{2}$$

its Fourier Transform is easy to find using (1).

**Remarks :**

1) expression (2) is a cousin of your expression (3).

2) All this makes sense only in the  **distributional context**. For example, $\dfrac{1}{4 \pi^2 k^2}$  in (1) is not integrable ; it is in fact a distribution called the **Finite Part** of $\dfrac{1}{4 \pi^2 k^2}.$

3) About the physical meaning of $\delta'$ as a "doublet", see the answer I gave [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1778778).

Comment: The integral you wrote for $\hat{f}(k)$ still doesn't converge. Also, I'm guessing $k$ is an integer here? That's applicable for Fourier transforms of period functions/functions on a circle, but not for Fourier transforms on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Eric Canton 1) In the distributional sense, you must drop the idea that you work with convergent integrals. 2) No, $k \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I am surprized I have been downvoted for an exact answer...

Comment: Thank you for your response. I applied your formula and time shift property to obtain
$$ \hat{f}(k) = \beta\delta(k)+\frac{\beta}{2\alpha}\hat{r}(k)(e^{-2\pi ik\alpha}-e^{2\pi ik\alpha})$$

Comment: @M. Nestor $\delta$ should be primed. You can even transform the second term into $\beta k \hat{r}(k)i sinc(2 \pi \alpha k)$ (card sine is often useful...)

Comment: @M. Nestor Sorry, 2 errors of mine  : this $\delta$ hasn't to be primed. The second term can be transformed into $-\beta k \hat{r}(k)i sinc(2 \pi \alpha k)$ with a minus sign in front.

Comment: @M. Nestor For the final expression, you will need the following property : $k \delta^{\prime}(k)=-\delta(k)$.

Comment: @JeanMarie indeed, I was objecting to writing $\hat{f}(k) =...$ at all, since the Fourier transform of such distributions isn't a function on $\mathbb{R}$. I think it could be helpful to present what you mean by "the distributional sense," i.e. you define the Fourier transform via integration against Schwartz ("rapidly decreasing") functions. *cf. Rudin's Functional Analysis, Definition 7.14*.

Comment: @JeanMarie I took the calculation further in an edit to my post, and if I am correct, I think I have reached a very satisfying form. Also, thank you Eric Canton for the literature reference.